# Maximum worker process set to 1 but there are multiple W3wp.exe for pool

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

There is an App Pool named `WadoAppPool` and I set `maximum worker process` to `1` and set `privateMemory` to `2048000` like:

[image]
[image]

but I don't know why there are multiple `W3wp.exe` for that app pool (this caused memory overflow):

[image]

Specs:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/failure Check if you enable orphan processes.

Comment: processes run longer if they become orphaned. another thing is you could try to set the CPU limit for the application pool set an action to KillW3p.<applicationPools>
   `<add name="DefaultAppPool">
     <cpu limit="80000" action="KillW3wp" resetInterval="00:02:00" />
   </add>
</applicationPools>`

Comment: But that doesn't answer the OP's question. If I set a MaxWorkerProcess to 1 I would expect that only w3wp.exe instance would be created for that AppPool.  I am facing the exact same scenario, where I have a AppPool configured to allow a max of 3 wp and the trace shows that sometimes that AppPool creates up to 6 wp.